# Dynamically inserting HTML into View through AJAX with JS Array in LARAVEL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hi I am new to Laravel having a situation like: I have a HTML form and loading some HTML like "partial.blade.php" using AJAX in Same form, that is working perfectly with static HTML but,

I want to send a JS Array of object with AJAX Request to Dynamically loading HTML Content like: Drop down in same form

Could any Guide me how Can i Pass JS Array to that piece of HTML so i can Render that Array in "partial.blade.php"

here is my code

this is main form HTML & Array i want to pass with this AJAX Request

```
var dataArray = $('#data1').val();
```

code included at last in HTML Form Page

```
$.ajax({                
            url: "add-property/residential",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { dataArr: dataArray },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#dynamicForm').html(response);
                //alert(response);
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert('Error....!');
            }
        });
```

here is my Route

```
Route::any('admin/add-property/residential',function() { return view('admin.residential'); });
```

all i want to receive that JS array in this piece of HTML that is dynamically loading

Comment: Js array into HTML?!!

Comment: I'm more than sure that `var dataArray = $('#data1').val();` must be returning a string. Even if that was a json array in php, it's still a string after adding to an input `value`. Did you try using `JSON.parse()` on it to convert it into JSON?

Comment: Thank for your Reply but yet  i didn't try this approach

Comment: only you got my point what i actually want to do

Comment: can you plz guide me with example

Comment: 1. i want to send server side array variable with ajax request.
--2. when ajax load that html.
--3. how i was able to receive that passed array again.

hope I cleared my point

Comment: If I understood correctly again this time, use `data: { dataArr: JSON.parse(dataArray) }` and `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`. On the server side, `$_GET['dataArr']` will contain all your json as `php Array`, if you want that back as json on server, do `json_encode($_GET['dataArr'])`. If you never need `php Array` on server, only `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in ajax should be enough and on server, `$_GET['dataArr']` contains your `String json`. What do you mean by *"2. when ajax load that html."*?

Comment: I'm not a `laravel` developer, so you might want to adapt `$_GET` to your framework specific convetion/variable, `$_GET` should still work nonetheless.

Comment: I was still receiving Empty Array in Success Response. I just got everything ok by Removing "processData: false" in AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to return the contents of a `view()` to an AJAX request, you can store the view as a variable and return in a JSON response:

```
public function apiResponse(){
  $html = view("admin.residential")->render();

  return response()->json(["html" => $html]);
}
```

In your AJAX request, you can access this as `response.html`:

```
success: function(response) {
  $("#dynamicForm").html(response.html);
}
```

To pass a variable from AJAX to the view, you can use the `request` object. At the top of your `routes/api` (or `routes/web.php`, whichever you're using) add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`, then in your Route inject that into the function:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
...
Route::any('admin/add-property/residential',function(Request $request){ 
  ...
});
```

Not that `$request` is available, you can access the data being sent in the AJAX request via `$request->input("dataArr");`, and pass that to the view partial using `->with();`:

```
Route::any('admin/add-property/residential',function(Request $request){ 

  $dataArr = $request->input("dataArr");
  $html = view("admin.residential")->with(["dataArr" => $dataArr])->render();

  return response()->json(["html" => $html]);
});
```

Comment: I Really appreciate your response but Actually I have some serverside variable in partial HTML when i load that HTML with AJAX Server Respond Undefined Variables

Comment: to over come that problem i want to send that Server side array variable Through Ajax so that when i load partial html i also want to receive that passed array variable again

Comment: can you guide me how to receive array variable sent from AJAX in Route Closure and pass to partial view

Comment: thanks for your time again I just learned how to put all view in a single variable to pass away. I have just fix my issue by removing the "processData: false" from AJAX now I am moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://codetheory.in/laravel-render-view-store-contents-variable/)

Instead of `return view('admin.residential');`

You need to do this: `return (string) View::make('admin.residential');`

**Edit**

If you want to receive data from the ajax, and then load the view, you could do something like this:

Import the `Request`.

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;`

Make your rote point to a specific `method` on a `controller`.

`Route::any('admin/add-property/residential',"YourController@returnView");`

Make your `function` to handle the data

```
public function returnView(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all(); // Here you will have all the data you send via AJ
    //Make sure the $data has all the necessary parameter to load the view
    $view = View::make('my_view', $data);//Here you will pass the data to the view
    return response()->json(["html" => $$view->render()]); // Using @TimLewis return
}
```

Comment: i have no issue to render partial html without server side variables

Comment: @ZeeshanDaDa I make a change to the code, I hope i can help you with your problem